# Mockito.mockedStatic for method with arguments

Tags: mocking, mockito

All the examples provided for mockedStatic method is for method without parameters. Is there a way to mock methods with parameters.

examples provided:
https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.4.6/org/mockito/Mockito.html#static_mocks

```
 mocked.when(Foo::method).thenReturn("bar");
 assertEquals("bar", Foo.method());
 mocked.verify(Foo::method);
 }
```

What I want:
I tried below and it does not work.

`mocked.when(Foo.methodWithParams("SomeValue"))`

Comment: one thing to be noted in above answer is that you need to use mockito-inline instead of mockito-core for mocking static methods

Answer (score 74, accepted):

**Edit - Mockito 3.7.7**

[Mockito 3.7.7](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/releases/tag/v3.7.7) unified order of verify parameters (Issue [#2173](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/2173))

Updated code:

```
try (MockedStatic<Foo> dummyStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(Foo.class)) {
    dummyStatic.when(() -> Foo.method("param1"))
               .thenReturn("someValue");
    // when
    System.out.println(Foo.method("param1"));
    //then
    dummyStatic.verify(
            () -> Foo.method("param1"),
            times(1), 
    );
}
```

**Original answer**

It is possible, you need to use a lambda instead of a method reference:

```
try (MockedStatic<Foo> dummyStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(Foo.class)) {
    dummyStatic.when(() -> Foo.method("param1"))
               .thenReturn("someValue");
    // when
    System.out.println(Foo.method("param1"));
    //then
    dummyStatic.verify(
            times(1), 
            () -> Foo.method("param1")
    );
}
```

Comment: FYI Looks like this is a deprecated approach now and should be reversed (https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.10.0/org/mockito/MockedStatic.html). Stupid I know but it shows up on IJ